# Why does Assuming[...] work in one case but not in another?

Tags: assumptions

Why does this work

```
Assuming[α > 0 && ϵ > 0 && t > 0,
 FullSimplify @ Integrate[(z^2 Exp[-α t (z^2 + ϵ)])/(z^2 + 1), {z, 0, ∞}]]
```

> ```
> (E^(-t α ϵ) (Sqrt[π] - E^(t α) π Sqrt[t α] Erfc[Sqrt[t α]]))/(2 Sqrt[t α])
> ```

but not this?

```
MyAssumptions := Assuming[α > 0 && ϵ > 0 && t > 0, #] &;
MyAssumptions[FullSimplify @ Integrate[(z^2 Exp[-α t (z^2 + ϵ)])/(z^2 + 1), {z, 0, ∞}]]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[
>   (E^(-t α ϵ) (Sqrt[π] - E^(t α) π Sqrt[t α] Erfc[Sqrt[t α]]))/(2 Sqrt[t α]),
>   Re[t α] > 0]
> ```

Comment: To other users: I'm sure this is a duplicate; I don't expect any votes for my answer but it was faster to post than to search, I'm tired, and a targeted example is probably more useful to the user anyway.  Please close if/when a duplicate is found.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your function must hold its argument or the Simplify will evaluate before the function even sees it.  Use:

```
Function[expr, Assuming[α > 0 && ϵ > 0 && t > 0, expr], HoldFirst]
```

Or:

```
SetAttributes[myAssumptions, HoldFirst]
myAssumptions[expr_] := Assuming[α > 0 && ϵ > 0 && t > 0, expr]
```

Comment: If it's a duplicate, I can't find it. +1.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to prevent the expression from evaluating before it is passed on to `Assuming`:

```
MyAssumptions := Assuming[α > 0 && ϵ > 0 && t > 0, #] &;
MyAssumptions[
 Unevaluated@
  FullSimplify@
   Integrate[(z^2 Exp[-α t (z^2 + ϵ)])/(z^2 + 1), {z, 
     0, ∞}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]